# How to insert javascript array data into a database?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, arrays

I'm trying to make an ecommerce site. So what I'm trying to do here is that I have two select tag, the value of the second tag should automatically be listed after selecting a particular data on the first select tag. Meaning suppose, the first tag is for 'Department' whereas the second tag is for categories. So if I select 'Electronics' in the first tag only(not all) categories which are inside Electronics(eg. laptop, smartphone, etc) should appear automatically, same case for cloth which should appear only(top wear, bottom wear, etc). And what I did is that I made the department in a select tag whereas I stored the categories in a javascript array. The following is the code for html...

```
 <select class="products" id="department_select" name="department" onchange="categoryChange(this);">
            <option value="empty">Select</option>
            <option value="Electronics">Electronics</option>
            <option value="Men's clothes">Men's clothes</option>
            <option vlaue="Women's clothes">Women's clothes</option>
            <option vlaue="Home & Kitchen">Home & Kitchen</option>
            <option vlaue="Sports & Fitness">Sports & Fitness</option>
        </select><br>
```

Below is the code where I stored the categories in javascript array..

```
<script>
    // array of possible countries in the same order as they appear in the country selection list 
    var categoryLists = new Array(5)
    categoryLists["empty"] = ["Select"];
    categoryLists["Electronics"] = ["Select","Camera", "Desktop", "Laptop", "Mobile", "Smart watch"];
    categoryLists["Men's clothes"] = ["Select","Foot wear", "Bottom wear", "Top wear", "Summer clothes", "Winter clothes"];
    categoryLists["Women's clothes"] = ["Select","Clothing", "Foot wear", "Saree", "Top wear", "Bottom wear"];
    categoryLists["Home & Kitchen"] = ["Select","Living Room Furniture", "Bedroom Furniture", "Office & Study", "Kitchen needs"];
    categoryLists["Sports & Fitness"] = ["Select","Cricket", "Football", "Gym Accessories"];

    /* CountryChange() is called from the onchange event of a select element. 
    * param selectObj - the select object which fired the on change event. 
    */ 
    function categoryChange(selectObj){
        // get the index of the selected option 
        var idx = selectObj.selectedIndex;
        // get the value of the selected option 
        var which = selectObj.options[idx].value;
        // use the selected option value to retrieve the list of items from the countryLists array 
        cList = categoryLists[which];
        // get the country select element via its known id 
        var cSelect = document.getElementById("category_select");
        // remove the current options from the country select 
        var len = cSelect.options.length;
        while(cSelect.options.length > 0){
            cSelect.remove(0);
        }
        var newOption;
        // create new options 
        for(var i=0; i<cList.length; i++){
            newOption = document.createElement("option");
            newOption.value = cList[i];// assumes option string and value are the same 

            newOption.text = cList[i];
            // add the new option 
            try{
                cSelect.add(newOption);
            }
            catch(e){
                cSelect.appendChild(newOption);
            }
        }
    }
```

So normally when i stored data from php i used the $categories = $_POST['categories'] and all. But the problem here is that I can't seem to find a way to store the javascript array data into the database. Especially since i'm storing one select tag using php and the second select tag using javascript.
So, guys if you could please help me out here. THANK YOU SO MUCHH...

Comment: You should use [Prepared Statements](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo). This link should give you everything you need to know. Your `$_POST` global variable will hold your array, from there, just `INSERT` it into your table.

Comment: @Jaquarh, so you are saying instead of using javascript i can do it in php using prepared statements? Because I can see the prepared statement in php

Comment: Javascript is a client side language. If you directly interact with SQL you will expose many security flaws. The only way to work with SQL is via a server side language like PHP. You can still send the data from JavaScript to PHP, but PHP will be responsible for connecting to the DB and storing the data

Answer (score 0):

To store an array into a database, you need to convert it to a string first.

```
//Convert to string
$categories = json_encode($categories);


//You now use $categories in your mysql queries
```